# Dynamic Collapse effect with Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I have been working on a project where I am stuck in a situation which is kind of weird. I have almost completed my task and at the end time I got a task to dynamically load Collapse/Expand feature which is already created using bootstrap. Here is my code whatever I am trying but somehow I am not getting solution for this.

```
<div class="panel internal_panel" *ngFor="let leader of leaders;let i = index;" >
    <div class="data_heading" [id]="'leader_heading'+i">
        <div class="data_left_col lead_lft_col">
            <h4 class="panel-title team_title leader_name">
                <a class="team_name" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="onTeamToggleClick(leader)" [attr.aria-expanded]="leader.isToggled"  [href]="'#leader_collapse'+i">
                   <i class="icon fas fa-plus"></i> <i class="icon fas fa-minus"></i> {{leader.FULL_NAME}}
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
    <div [id]="'leader_collapse'+i" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'leader_collapse'+i" class="panel-collapse team-collapse collapse in" [attr.aria-expanded]="leader.isToggled">
        <div class="panel-body employee_panel">
            <div class="panel-group">
               // Some code here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I am handling Toggle event and when on reload of data I want to rebind the value. I have used "isToggled" here to to set the whether it is collapsed or not. Now here if you see class we have already applied to open it by adding "collapse in". I have tried my luck by using it with `[ngClass]` but I failed miserably. So Kindly help me set collapse/expand  event here.